# Which method is faster and why np.sum(arr) vs arr.sum()?

Tags: python, numpy, sum, time-complexity, space-complexity

Which is a faster method? like aren't they both the same?

```
start = time.time()
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,12])
total_price =  np.sum(arr[arr < 7])* 2.14

print(total_price)
print('Duration: {} seconds'.format(time.time() - start))
```

```
start = time.time()
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,12])
total_price =  (arr[arr<7]).sum()* 2.14

print(total_price)
print('Duration: {} seconds'.format(time.time() - start))
```

On running the code, again and again, both of them give differing resultant execution time. Sometimes the former method is faster and sometimes later.

Comment: arr.sum implies a numpy array i think ... so its probably faster most of the time (although it might also hook into the normal sum and vectorize that)

Comment: Probably numpy is the faster but since you have the code already, run it a bunch of times and see which one is faster. The hands on experiment will give the ultimate answer.

Comment: If you're going to do benchmarking, don't include `print` in the code being timed.  And learn about [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html).

Comment: The difference should be ignorable. If the type is known, i prefer `arr.sum()`. I guess  `np.sum` is more generic approach if the type does not support `sum`.

Comment: @MarkRansom or even better use cProfile (or %prun) :P if you really want to get nitty gritty with it

Comment: Both are basically the same except that in the first snippet "np.sum" has first to check the type of its parameter (can be neglected). After that the numpy array can be processed in the same way.

Comment: @MichaelButscher they *can* be processed the same way, but are they?  Since a numpy array has a well defined memory layout, it can use low-level vector instructions to get a speedup.  Don't know if it does or not.

Comment: I I think they are just the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

Removing the giant docstring, the [code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.24.2/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L2188) for `np.sum` is

```
@array_function_dispatch(_sum_dispatcher)
def sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=np._NoValue,
        initial=np._NoValue, where=np._NoValue):

    if isinstance(a, _gentype):
        # 2018-02-25, 1.15.0
        warnings.warn(
            "Calling np.sum(generator) is deprecated, and in the future will give a different result. "
            "Use np.sum(np.fromiter(generator)) or the python sum builtin instead.",
            DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=3)

        res = _sum_(a)
        if out is not None:
            out[...] = res
            return out
        return res

    return _wrapreduction(a, np.add, 'sum', axis, dtype, out, keepdims=keepdims,
                          initial=initial, where=where)
```

`array_function_dispatch` handles [`__array_function__` overrides](https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0018-array-function-protocol.html) that non-NumPy types might provide, while `_wrapreduction` is responsible for making sure `np._NoValue` isn't passed to the underlying implementation, as well as deciding whether to call the `sum` method (for non-array input) or `add.reduce` (for array input).

So it does a bunch of checks to handle non-array inputs, then eventually passes the task to `np.add.reduce` if the input is an array.

Meanwhile, `np.ndarray.sum` is [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.24.2/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L2392):

```
static PyObject *
array_sum(PyArrayObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    NPY_FORWARD_NDARRAY_METHOD("_sum");
}
```

where `NPY_FORWARD_NDARRAY_METHOD` is a macro that forwards the operation to [`numpy.core._methods._sum`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.24.2/numpy/core/_methods.py#L47):

```
def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False,
         initial=_NoValue, where=True):
    return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
```

and `umr_sum` is an alias for `np.add.reduce`.

Both code paths eventually end up at `np.add.reduce`, but the `ndarray.sum` code path doesn't involve all the pre-check work for non-array input, because the array already knows it's an array.

In these tests the calculation time itself is small enough that the extensive prechecks make a big difference:

```
In [607]: timeit np.sum(np.arange(1000))                                                 
15.4 µs ± 42.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [608]: timeit np.arange(1000).sum()                                                   
12.2 µs ± 29.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [609]: timeit np.add.reduce(np.arange(1000))                                          
9.19 µs ± 17.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

`numpy` has a number of function/method pairs like this.  Use which ever is most convenient - and looks prettiest in your code!

Comment: Thanx! I hope there's no complex mechanism behind both of the methods.

Comment: https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0018-array-function-protocol.html#performance talks about performance of `np.sum` in the current version which adds `@array_function_dispatch` layer.

Comment: Ever since they added the [`__array_function__` mechanism](https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0018-array-function-protocol.html), the overhead for `np.sum` (and most NumPy functions) has gotten even worse.

Comment: ...wait, `__array_function__` was already in when this answer was posted. The answer just left out the decorator that handles it.